# How these websites are fetching FB profile id from username

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to latest Facebook graph API we cannot fetch user / profile id from Facebook username as

> graph.facebook.com/username

Then how these websites are fetching user / profile id from usernames.
https://lookup-id.com/
http://findfacebookid.com/
http://findmyfbid.com/
etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are scraping the profile, which is not allowed. If you need to get a User ID, authorize the User with your App and you will get an App Scoped ID. That´s all you need.